# Reference error from react inside meteor only when minified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, minify

I'm using react inside a meteor app. It works fine when running in development mode, but when I run it in production mode and the code is minified, I get the below `ReferenceError` and minified react error in the browser console when the app loads. The same thing happens when I try to deploy it.

It's being minified using the built in [standard-minifier-js](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/standard-minifier-js). When I `meteor remove` this package, it works fine, so it's definitely the minification.

I'm stumped. I know that the line in question is part of `react-dom`, but I can't figure out which part or why it's only throwing an error after minification.

The [react error decoder](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=183) says:

`Should have found an error boundary. This error is likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue.`

Which isn't much more helpful. Any ideas what could be causing the error, or how to troubleshoot it? I'm using the latest versions of everything, AFAICT:

- react version: 16.0.0
- meteor version: 1.5.2.2
- standard-minifier-js version: 2.1.2

Thanks.

```
b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5149 ReferenceError: av is not defined
    at b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4003
    at sv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4107)
    at dv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4104)
    at beginWork (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4243)
    at ov (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4941)
    at fv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:4976)
    at lv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5028)
    at mv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5182)
    at bv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5164)
    at Object.updateContainer (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:8400)
pv @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5149
lv @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5042
mv @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5182
bv @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5164
updateContainer @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:8400
(anonymous) @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5603
unbatchedUpdates @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5258
Dr @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5602
render @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:8559
(anonymous) @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:93855
s @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:315
u @ b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:321
b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:3148 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #183; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=183 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at ot (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:3148)
    at lv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5043)
    at mv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5182)
    at bv (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5164)
    at Object.updateContainer (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:8400)
    at b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5603
    at Object.unbatchedUpdates (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5258)
    at Dr (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:5602)
    at render (b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:8559)
    at b2413faf75d38415b6ec79874ae1bd18fb0a8af3.js?meteor_js_resource=true:formatted:93855
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried another minification package, [uglifyjs2](https://atmospherejs.com/ssrwpo/uglifyjs2), instead of standard-minifier-js and that appears to have worked. But it seems like there's a bug here with either react or meteor.

```
meteor remove standard-minifier-js
meteor add ssrwpo:uglifyjs2
```